# Is this vectorial identity between operators true?

Tags: vector-analysis

$$\nabla^2(\mathbf{t} u(\mathbf{r}) ) =\mathbf{t} div(\nabla u(\mathbf{r}))$$
Where $\mathbf{t}$ is constant vector and $\nabla^2$ is the vector laplacian (defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes. It looks true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: $\nabla^2 (tu) = \partial_i^2 (t_i u_i) = t_i (\partial_i^2 u_i) = t . \operatorname{div} (\nabla u)$.

Comment: Your demonstration holds only in cartesiancoordinates I'd say, is it correct? Otherwise you can't define the laplacian as you have done in your first passage.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming you're in flat $\mathbb{R}^n$. Otherwise, throw a bunch of metric coefficients in, choose a convenient local coordinate chart, etc.